# Why in VBA is the variable name "I" always translated as "i"?

Tags: vba, naming-conventions

When I Type in

```
For I = 1 to 9
```

VBA re-edits it to

```
For i = 1 to 9
```

Comment: VBA is case insensitive. If you have that variable defined (dim) else where, it'll change the case to that definition in all places where it's used

Comment: Moreover, (capital) *I* is not a good variable name as it can easily be mixed up with *l* (lower-case L).

Comment: In my code, a single integer is an easy name in a For statement.

Comment: And I've gone over my code and there is no variable "I" (Capital "I") that I can find defined or used.

Comment: I have noticed when I get one of these case changing problems, if I take the whole code spec into Notepad, I can substitute the upper case character for the lower, reload it back into VBA and it's fixed.  But sometimes it reverts to the original lower case string.  Maybe there is a reference already someplace elsewhere in the code.  But again when I do a case sensitive search, I don't find anything.  And the variable has to have a global definition for this to work like this, and I can't find one.

Comment: So I tried starting with a new notebook (Nothing defined).  I defined a function with a For Loop controlled by "I".  VBA turned the "I" into an "i".